# MVC5 Project - Naming Conventions

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, naming-conventions

I've started a new MVC project, and this is my first where its pure MVC without CMS integrations or otherwise. I'm looking for advice on naming conventions, as I am aware there are going to be a **lot** of controls and forms that are re-used.

Is it sensible to create say a Controls Controller for these re-usable items and call them from my views as appropriate? Also, would there then be a way to stop someone navigating to that Controls/MyControl URL directly?

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 1):

To stop one from navigating to Controls/MyControl you just need to add [`ChildActionOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
ActionResult MyControl(...){...}
```

Naming/grouping is up to you - you can start with one controller and see if controls need to be split into groups later.

Note that you may not even need controller for most of the controls as long as they just show data - `@Html.RenderPartial("MyControl", dataForControl)` may be enough (assuming Razor and existence of "MyControl.cshtml")

Comment: It's `[ChildActionOnly]`, actually.